# php/mysql alternative to openinviter cloudsponge

Tags: php, mysql, contacts

With considerable time and effort, I installed openinviter as suggested by some posts on SO to get contact info from user address books  However, I've since discovered that others here and elsewhere on the web consider openinviter out of date.  It is working for me for gmail--though I haven't tested every provider--but most posts on the site are from a year or two ago.  I'm reluctant to spend a lot of time integrating it if it is now unreliable and not maintained.  Some say the industry is moving toward oauth as used by cloudsponge (which costs money.)  Others suggest using the published apis from Gmail and a few others  I have already had one question closed on this topic as not code specific but it seems that it would be far more useful to know what people consider up to date for grabbing contacts rather what is best code to implement an out of date script.  Are there any newer, better alternatives to openinviter other than cloudsponge?  From anyone doing it, what is the current best practice for getting user contacts?  Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Janrain Engage can help you accomplish this, utilizing our get_contacts API endpoint.
Check out the documentation for the down and dirty:

http://developers.janrain.com/documentation/api/get_contacts/

Comment: Any step by setp guide for implementation?